# How to Play 3gpp files with Angular Js App

Tags: angularjs, audiojs

I have tried ngAudio but it doesn't support 3gpp.

How can Play 3gpp files in my app without asking for any plugin to download?

I Mean to say I'm able to Play mp3, wav files using native audio player.

I want to achieve same for 3gp format too.

Please suggest for any Angular plugin or any idea?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem you have is not really related to AngularJS but with the codecs of common browsers. I believe that Safari runs the 3GPP codec but that is probably it. You should instead consider running a converter on your server, so you can play more browser-friendly formats.

I suggest you take a look at ["ffmpeg"](https://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html), which is a "framework able to, decode, encode, transcode, mux, demux, stream, filter and play" (taken directly from their web). You haven't mentioned the server you are running on your backend, but yous shouldn't have much problem finding a wrapper to run ffmpeg, or build your own. If you are running node then I suggest this library:

[Fluent FFMPEG](https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg)

After you run it, is very simple to convert your files. Just check their docs.

Then you could just use the native audio player or some other library.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I load it on the fly using a url, actually it is saved on some amazon cloud server that i don't have much about,

ngAudio.load("http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/demo/_mp3/rain.mp3");

As this is an mp3 it is played successfully but I my case I'm able to fetch the file but it is not Playing due to some codec issue.

To mention when I download and play with VLC media Player Its getting played but with windows media player its not.

So I suppose there is some issue with codecs.

Is there any way so that I can covert it after loading or so.

Comment: Mmm, I don't know that. But you could offer different formats of the same files, to be played with different codecs.